# Uploading a code file to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to upload a code file to wordpress so that people can download it from my website. However, when I try to upload, it gives me this error:

> sorry this file type is not permitted for security reasons

I am trying to upload a `.m` file to my website. Need some guidance on how to solve this issue.

Comment: I believe wordpress only allows image files, but some forum posts mention this plugin may help you: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gd-bbpress-attachments/

Comment: tried this. not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Codex explains here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes) how you can change the allowed mime types, through the `upload_mimes` filter.

If you mean a *Matlab* file with the `.m` extension, then you could try the following plugin:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Support Matlab (.m) uploads
 * Description: Support uploads of Matlab .m files.
 * Plugin URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27785139/2078474
 * Author:      birgire, Codex
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes' );

function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes = array() )
{ 
    // Add file extension 'extension' with mime type 'mime/type'
    // $existing_mimes['extension'] = 'mime/type';

    // ----------------------
    // Your modifications:
    // Support for .m files:
    $existing_mimes['m'] = 'application/matlab';
    // ----------------------

    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

where you might have to adjust the mime part to your needs.

Comment: Yes I m referring to Matlab file. But where do you add it to? functions.php?

Comment: Yes, you can add this to `functions.php` in your current theme, or better yet use it as a plugin: Save the code snippet into the `/wp-content/plugins/allow-mfiles/allow-mfiles.php` file and activate the plugin.